# Is there a way to show how many people are following me on Twitter and a standard "Follow me on Twitter" button?

Tags: twitter

Currently I'm using a custom (rather ugly) image:

[image: "follow us on twitter"]

Is there something more standardized?

Can I show how many people follow me on Twitter, just as the 'Like' button shows how many people like my site?

Answer (score 4):

A "Like" on Facebook is usually is a "Star" (or "add to favorites") on Twitter.
For an overview of tweets that received stars, [Favstar.fm](http://favstar.fm/) seems to be the most common site.
As long as it is about single tweets the star seems to be the established symbol of "I like".

When it comes to just linking to a related Twitter account, I guess there are multiple button-like [images that Twitter provides](http://twitter.com/goodies/buttons) for linking.

Like this one [image: Follow Me - button], which looks similar to your custom one.

I hope this is helpful, otherwise it seems I did not fully understand what you were looking for.

Comment: Edited my question - I'd like something that shows how many followers I have.

Comment: this is tricky. as you are looking for something common or already established, I have to admit I've never seen something like the thing you're looking for (speaking against the "well established" kind of thing). Plus: I wouldn't use your followercount analogue to facebook's "likes". That doesn't seem "appropriate twitter protocol", somehow :)

Answer (score 4):

Twitter now officially offers a [Tweet button](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet) which shows how many people have tweeted the URL of the current page it's on (or another page if your customise it).